# Merging two foreign key columns into EmbeddedID

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two tables (Product and Supermarket). They have Many to Many relationship so I created an additional table ProductSupermarket. I want the last table to have only one column which is merging the two foreign keys. This is what I have implemented so far but I am stuck with two columns in the ProductSupermarket - product_id and supermarket_id ..

> Product

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "product_id")
   private Long productID;
   ..
```

> Supermarket

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "supermarket")
public class Supermarket{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "supermarket_id")
   private Long supermarketID;
   ...
```

> ProductSupermarketKey

```
@Embeddable
public class ProductSupermarketKey implements Serializable {
  @Column(name="product_id")
  private Long productID;

  @Column(name="supermarket_id")
  private Long supermarketID;

  public ProductSupermarketKey (){}

  public ProductSupermarketKey (Long productID, Long supermarketID) {
    this.productID = productID;
    this.supermarketID = supermarketID;
  }
```

> ProductSupermarket

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "date_event")
public class ProductSupermarket implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private ProductSupermarketKey id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Product product;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "supermarket_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Supermarket supermarket;
```

Comment: You can check here: https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tip-many-to-many-association-with-additional-attributes/

Comment: Thank you, but implementing what this article says I am still with two columns instead of one

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "I want the last table to have only one column which is merging the two foreign keys." ?

Comment: I want table ProductSupermarket with a column "product_supermarket_id" which merges the two primary keys, for example '15' - product with id 1 and supermarket with id 5

Comment: 'Merges' as in 'concatenates'? You realize there are going to be clashes, right?

Comment: 'Merges' as Composite primary key